# ResourceCulture System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Invalid Image Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization

I have added a resource file to my xamarin app.when running with

> Common Language Runtime Exceptions checked

I get the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Invalid Image

however the resources are loaded fine.

Am I missing the obvious? Should I initialize something?

Comment: File build action should be Embedded Resource.

Comment: Please add more details this is not enough for us to understand the issue

Comment: File action is set to embedded resource. @G.hakim there no more detail  . Just add a resource file to your app and then break on errors settings and resourceculture will throw an error

Comment: Are you reference a `imageName` which does't exist in your project? For example `<Image Source=""/>`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  reading text .simple text

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my side, can you provide a simple demo which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem here! One resx file in my NetStandard project as Embedded Resource and Clr Exceptions checked. It works fine, but there is still an exception..